# Max number of columns and column length in Vertica?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, vertica

We have some 3rd party marketing data that can take up to 3000 columns, and some of the column names have 300~400 characters.

According to Vertica official docs(HP Vertica Analytics Platform Version 7.0.x Documentation), it says 1600 is the max.

However, according to this article: http://www.dbms2.com/2012/07/28/some-vertica-6-features/, Vertica has effectively unlimited amount of columns.

So mayI ask is Vertica's max number of columns? And the max number of characters that can fit into a column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there can be varying data lengths for each column, the real restriction is on total row length, which is [32,768,000 bytes](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemLimits.htm). This, as well as the maximum column limit of 1600 still apply except on Flex tables.

The above documentation also provides the maximum length for a column name to be 128 bytes.

Comment: thank you for this information! Most of my 3000 columns are a single character, 'T' or 'F'. Does this mean I can blow past the 1600 column limit? And I assume I'm still restricted by the column name size of 128 bytes?

Comment: Unfortunately not; unless you're using Flex for exploration (not analytics). There are a few options, but your best bet will probably be to join a few tables.

Comment: Thanks again. I suppose you don't know of any db's out there that support thousands of columns, large column names, and sql functionality such as 'join' and 'group by'

Comment: Again, Vertica can do what you described in Flex. You won't get great performance but the functionality is there.

Comment: Thank you again. By the way, any tips on how bad the performance will be? Is it like mapreduce level of slow? We have a 2 semi large tables with a few gigs each, and we're hoping a join and aggregation takes less than 10 seconds.

Comment: @JeffLL few gigs is not much. I can't give you an estimate on performance, but definitely will be better than running a reduce job. Have you downloaded the trial of Vertica?

Comment: actually, we have a dev cluster and I'm now trying to load data into it. I do hope flex tables allow us to do joins and group bys(not in the documentation)!

Comment: @JeffLL Flex can work really well if it is a good fit.  Materialize your predicate columns.

Answer (score 0):

A quick web-search gives me several links that are:
1. Official Vertica pages.
2. More recent than your dbms2 link.

All off them show the column limit as 1600, and the maximum field name length as 128 bytes.

For example:
- http://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/10538.htm
-https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemLimits.htm
-https://community.vertica.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/Maximum-number-of-columns/td-p/208069

Comment: Downvoting because of outdated documentation as well as not accurate for all components of the platform.